# Revelation 11:2 literal or figurative?

Tags: revelation, prophecy, john-the-revelator

"but do not measure the court outside the temple; leave that out, for it is given over to the nations, and they will trample the holy city for forty-two months." **(Rev 11:2 - ESV)**

But exclude the outer court; do not measure it, because it has been given to the Gentiles. They will trample on the holy city for 42 months. **(Rev 11:2 - NIV)**

- Has this event already taken place or is it a future event?
- Is it a literal or figurative temple/courtyard?

Answer (score 4):

Before diving into Revelation, please read:

- the other prophetic works, since the same themes appear in all the prophetic works, but with different variations. E.g. the new Jerusalem, the four beasts, the four horsemen, locusts, the pit, etc, are all common motifs.
- read about the temple. I recommend "The Temple: Its Ministry and Services" by Edersheim, it's a famous book you can find for [free](https://ccel.org/ccel/edersheim/temple.html). Then things like the court of the gentiles, court of women, the 24 elders, the two lampstands, the bronze altar, altar of incense, coals on the altar, etc, will make more sense.

### The Court of Gentiles

[image: Temple Courts]

The temple has courts, the outermost court, open to all, is the [court of gentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple#Court_of_the_Gentiles) where gentiles are allowed to go. This was a bazaar filled with pilgrims, money changers, people selling livestock and doves for sacrifice, priests directing people, etc. During the high holy days hundreds of thousands of people would go through this court.

But gentiles can go no further than the court of gentiles. This is where Jesus drove out the money changers:

John 2.14-17

> In the temple courts he found people selling cattle, sheep and doves,
> and others sitting at tables exchanging money. So he made a whip
> out of cords, and drove all from the temple courts, both sheep and
> cattle; he scattered the coins of the money changers and overturned
> their tables. To those who sold doves he said, “Get these out of
> here! Stop turning my Father’s house into a market!” His disciples
> remembered that it is written: “Zeal for your house will consume me.”

[image]

Beyond that is the court of women where only jews could go, both male and female. But female jews were not allowed beyond the court of women.  Then there was the court of priests where the sacrifices were performed at the brazen altar and then the entrance to the Sanctuary (the main temple building with the holy place and most holy place).

Thus unbelievers are allowed to "trample" or defile the Temple as long as the Temple resides in this world, because as long as there is a Temple the court of the gentiles is available to the gentiles. But this availability, this mixing in which the church must coexist with non-believers, and is thus persecuted by non-believers, will come to an end. The court of the gentiles is also referred to as "the outer court", and so appears in prophetic works, whereas the court of women and priests are referred to as "inner courts". This is the interpretation to Rev 11.2

> But exclude the outer court; do not measure it, because it has been
> given to the Gentiles. They will trample on the holy city for 42
> months.

This is the entire world -- e.g. you have gentiles mixing with believers in the outer court, then the inner courts, then the holy place and most holy place. Thus everything that happens, happens in the temple (counting both the courts and Sanctuary).

### Is Prophetic imagery "real" or "figurative"

The court of gentiles was a real place, but the temple being described in prophecy is spiritual, and it is this spiritual pattern against which all three sanctuaries (tabernacle, Solomon's Temple, Herod's Temple) were modeled.

That does not mean it is "figurative" per se, since God is spirit and God is real, not figurative. However all prophecy is a view into spiritual things, not sensual things, so if you are expecting literal streets paved with gold you will be disappointed. Prophecy is a set of visions, of images, and prophecy as a genre is a series of glimpses of the Temple, since the temple is the gateway between man and God, where God resides, and revelation of God is what prophecy is about. Thus we can also interpret prophecy as a description of what is happening within us, as we are the temple of God. It is the "physical" world that is a metaphor, as it is a type and shadow of the spiritual temple. So God told Moses to construct the tabernacle according to the pattern he saw in the revelation on Sinai:

Ex 25.8-9

> And let them make me a sanctuary; that I may dwell among them.
> **According to all that I shew thee, after the pattern of the
> tabernacle**, and the pattern of all the instruments thereof, even so
> shall ye make it.

Thus the physical manifestation is a pattern or figurative image of the spiritual reality. Similarly the natural world is a pattern of the spiritual world - a type or shadow. Something transient, ephemeral, illusory, whereas the spiritual is real, permanent, and eternal. The world that we can see and touch is just a metaphor for things happening in the spirit. Therefore it's incorrect to call prophecy symbolic, although for practical reasons we do that. What we should do is call the world of the senses symbolic of what is revealed in prophecy.

Hebrews 10.1

> For the law, **possessing a shadow of the good things that are about to
> come, not the form of things itself**, is never able ⌊year by year⌋ by
> means of the same sacrifices which they offer without interruption to
> make perfect those who draw near

1 Chron 29.15

> For we are strangers before thee, and sojourners, as were all our
> fathers: **our days on the earth are as a shadow, and there is none
> abiding.**

Job 8.9

> For we are but of yesterday, and know nothing, Because **our days
> upon earth are a shadow**

Eccl 6.12

> For who knoweth what is good for man in this life, **all the days of his
> vain life which he spendeth as a shadow?** for who can tell a man what
> shall be after him under the sun?

Heb 8.3-5 describes the services in the physical temple as types and shadows of Christ:

> For every high priest is ordained to offer gifts and sacrifices:
> wherefore it is of necessity that this man have somewhat also to
> offer.  For if he were on earth, he should not be a priest, seeing
> that there are priests that offer gifts according to the law:  **Who
> serve unto the example and shadow of heavenly things**, as Moses was
> admonished of God when he was about to make the tabernacle: for, See,
> saith he, that thou **make all things according to the pattern shewed
> to thee in the mount**.

Col 2.16-17

> Let no man therefore judge you in meat, or in drink, or in respect
> of an **holy day, or of the new moon, or of the sabbath days:
> Which are a shadow of things to come; but the body is of Christ.**

So in our current shadow of reality we live together with unbelievers, and this coexistence is a metaphor for the outer court of the spiritual temple being trampled upon, but this is a temporary situation. With the interpretation of the temple being within us, we can say that there are aspects of our own inner life in which gentiles (or the world) is trampling, but this too will be removed. This is how I would interpret the passage.

Comment: Just read this. Superb answer! Love the courtyard images. I just finished handwriting my own answer, which expounds on the figurative/symbolic/spiritual theme but then takes yet another tack. It will follow in due course. Well done Robert.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your detailed contribution. "Female jews were not allowed to beyond the court of women". I think you might have missed a go, allowed to go beyond!  Would you call this temple also symbolic 2 Thess 2:4? Are you talking of [This One](http://www.ntslibrary.com/PDF%20Books/The%20Temple%20by%20Alfred%20Edersheim.pdf) by Edersheim?

Comment: Thanks @DanielDahlberg I added a link, cleaned up the language, added bold formatting to the quotes.

Comment: @Robert Good but you did not confirm if I got right book [the temple](http://www.ntslibrary.com/PDF%20Books/The%20Temple%20by%20Alfred%20Edersheim.pdf)

Comment: I put a link to the book -- it's the same book as you have. It's public domain.

Comment: "What we should do is call the world of the senses symbolic of what is revealed in prophecy." Bingo.  Before creation there was only God. He is the real reality. We are the void within him, this life is the shadow. We are in the 'dinner theater' of the reality of God.

Answer (score 3):

***Revelation 11:2 literal or figurative?***

John is instructed to measure the temple of God, the altar, and those who worship there. He is given a measuring rod to do this. The image of measuring is used in several places throughout Scripture. Sometimes the imagery is used of a plumb line as the people are measured against the standard of God’s laws.

> **2 Kings 21:13**: "And I will stretch over Jerusalem the measuring line of Samaria, and the plumb line of the house of Ahab, and I will wipe Jerusalem as one wipes a dish, wiping it and turning it upside down."

Sometimes the imagery is used to measure those who are righteous.

> **Zechariah 2:1-5**: "And I lifted my eyes and saw, and behold, a man with a measuring line in his hand! <sup>2</sup>Then I said, ‘Where are you going?’ And he said to me, ‘To measure Jerusalem, to see what is its width and what is its length.’ <sup>3</sup>And behold, the angel who talked with me came forward, and another angel came forward to meet him <sup>4</sup>and said to him, ‘Run, say to that young man, "Jerusalem shall be inhabited as villages without walls, because of the multitude of people and livestock in it. <sup>5</sup>And I will be to her a wall of fire all around, declares the LORD, and I will be the glory in her midst.”‘“

At the end of the Book of Revelation we will see the city called the New Jerusalem, representing the people of God, being measured:

> **Revelation 21:15-17**: “And the one who spoke with me had a measuring rod of gold to measure the city and its gates and walls. <sup>16</sup>The city lies foursquare, its length the same as its width. And he measured the city with his rod, 12,000 stadia [1,500 miles]. Its length and width and height are equal. <sup>17</sup>He also measured its wall, 144 cubits [72 yards] by human measurement, which is also an angel’s measurement.”

In Ezekiel, chapter 40, the prophet sees a vision of a person with a measuring reed in his hand. He is measuring the new temple of God and is to prophesy about the coming glory of the new temple.

The temple in the New Testament represents the true, holy people of God. In Revelation 3:12 we read that those who conquer will be made “a pillar in the temple of my God. Never shall he go out of it.” Paul also repeatedly taught that the people of God are God’s temple.

> **1 Corinthians 3:16**: "Do you not know that *you are God’s temple and that God’s Spirit dwells in you*?” (emphasis added).

> **2 Corinthians 6:16**: "What agreement has the temple of God with idols? For *we are the temple of the living God*; as God said, ‘I will make my dwelling among them and walk among them, and I will be their God, and they shall be my people’” (emphasis added).

Many espouse a futurist method of interpretation to the Book of Revelation. They see the images of the temple in Ezekiel 40-48 and Revelation 11 and feel that a physical temple will have to be rebuilt one day to fulfill these prophecies. However, they are overlooking what Ezekiel prophesied in his day, which ultimately found its fulfillment in being joined to Christ:

> **Ephesians 2:18-21**: "So then you are no longer strangers and aliens, but you are fellow citizens with the saints and members of the household of God, <sup>20</sup>built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Christ Jesus himself being the cornerstone, <sup>21</sup>in whom the whole structure, being joined together, grows into a holy temple in the Lord.”

Christ is the cornerstone of this temple, while the apostles and prophets are the foundation. We are being built into the holy temple of the Lord, a steady process in which new members are added to the Lord's Church every day. We should not think that only a small group of Christians see this temple as a spiritual temple to the Lord.<sup>1</sup>

Therefore, when we read about the temple of God in Revelation 11:1 we are reading about the full compliment of the true people of God. They are measured for protection from spiritual harm. As we have already seen in the book and will see again later in this chapter, the measuring cannot mean that they will not be killed.

The seals have revealed that the servants of God would be killed but their salvation is secure even though they will physically die. The measuring of the worshipers is a guarantee that they are members in the heavenly, spiritual temple irrespective of what happens to them on earth.

<sup>1</sup> Even the Qumran community, those who wrote the Dead Sea Scrolls, spiritualized Ezekiel’s temple. They declared the temple in Jerusalem as apostate and considered themselves the true spiritual temple (1QS 5:5-6; 8:4-10; 9:3-6; 11:7ff; CD 3:19-4:6; 4QFlor 1:2-9). They even used measurement imagery to describe the security of this temple (1QH 6:26).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution +1 You answer came in last yet did reveal something new =) "Sometimes the imagery is used of a plumb line as the people are measured against the standard of God’s laws." very good indeed to bring up the measuring part and to co-relate it to the plump-line! To the apostels and prophets being the foundation, You also have the saints  stones beside pillars1 Pet 2:5 And you are living stones that God is building into his spiritual temple.

Comment: Have just seen this after finishing my own answer, there having been only 2 answers when I started posting. Another great answer indeed.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to determine whether this event has already taken place or whether it is still future is to work out whether Revelation 11:1-2 speaks of a literal or a figurative temple/courtyard. It may even be needed, thereafter, to ***consider the possibility of this outer courtyard exemption having started with Christ's ascension and continuing right until he returns.***

Because verse 1 starts with "***And*** there was given me a reed like unto a rod", this is a continuation of what was said before, about the prophetic ministry John was given, which started with him eating a little book that tasted sweet as honey in his mouth but which then made his belly bitter. After he'd done that, he was given that measuring reed. Was his eating of the little scroll from the angel literal? Of course not! Then why would anyone think the measuring, or the courts, would be literal?

However, this should remind us of an Old Testament section where the prophet Ezekiel was given a vision of God's city where a man who appeared as brass (brass standing for God's judgment) had a measuring reed with which to do much measuring, including an inner and outer court. It was all about the abominations of the house of Israel, even inside the temple, and God's coming judgment (chapter 44). Here is an explanation of the significant connection between Ezekiel and John's respective visions, first re. Rev. 11:1:

> "This is a figure taken from Ezekiel 40:5, where the prophet sees a
> measuring reed... with this the measurements are taken of the mystical
> temple of Ezekiel chapters 40 to 43.. 'In the man's hand a measuring
> reed of six six cubits long by the cubit and an hand breadth.' Now,
> three palms of the hand measured one span. And two spans equalled one
> cubit. Therefore six palms of an hand measured one cubit. But the
> measurement of the mystical temple *was not according to that cubit*.
> The wording is this, Ezekiel 40:5, 'a measuring reed of six cubits by
> the cubit and an hand breadth.'
>
> That means that the reed was not merely six cubits - which was the
> measure of an earthly man - because to each of the six cubits was
> *added* an hand's breadth... six hand's breadth *equalled* one cubit. Then six cubits of a cubit *and* an hand's breadth actually amounted
> to *seven* cubits. Perfect measurement. The measure of the perfect
> Man, that is, the heavenly Man, which is Christ. By this measure the
> mystical temple is to be measured.
>
> This is the measure of conformity to the image of Christ, Rom. 8:29,
> not only individually, but of all such individuals corporately united:
> it is the *temple* that is to be measured. 'All the building fitly
> framed together groweth unto an holy temple in the Lord: in whom ye' -
> plural - 'are builded together for an habitation of God through the
> Spirit.' Eph. 2:21,22.
>
> Therefore, spiritually, the temple is no structure of stone, mortar,
> or wood. It is the inward habitation of God; Father, Son, and Holy
> Ghost, dwelling within the unity of the saints separated from the
> world and gathered together in the Spirit.
>
> This appears in Eph. 4:13 concerning the edifying of the body of
> Christ, 'till we all come in the unity of the faith, and of the
> knowledge of the Son of God, unto a perfect man, unto the *measure* of
> the stature of the fulness of Christ.' Where *his* fulness, dwelling
> in the interior of the temple, that is, the saints gathered in unity,
> transforms the whole living company into his own likeness.
>
> Not only is John given a book to eat, but also a reed to measure. The
> one is *to* the nations; the other is *for* the temple. He is not to
> measure the outer court, for that is to be trodden under foot of the
> Gentiles for forty and two months, the same period in which the two
> witnesses are to prophesy...
>
> The reed represents the prophet's ability... to measure what is of God
> on earth at a given time, as opposed to what is merely supposed to be
> of God on earth at that time. This figure cannot possibly be confined
> to John, any more than the temple can be limited to the apostles'
> lifetime. Both these figures signify principles which can and must
> apply throughout the age... till the day of judgment.
>
> ...This measures where his presence *dwells*... The altar was the
> place where sin was condemned in the flesh and put away by the
> offering up of the body of Jesus once and for all. This becomes the
> measure. Nothing of the flesh is tolerated past the altar, which is at
> the threshold of the house...
>
> The flesh - if not constantly kept mortified by the Spirit - will seek
> to claim the altar, and enter in some other way, setting up its own
> measurements, pretending to experiences to which it is foreign,
> assuming a false spirituality, tending strange fire... avoiding the
> man with the measuring rod." *The Revelation of Jesus Christ,* pp
> 251-255, John Metcalfe

Without grasping what verse 1 means, verse 2 will be in limbo. What is to be measured, and with what, determines the meaning of verse 2, which is what is being asked about. Now that the inner court and its symbolic measurement has been explained, it is easy to see what casting out the outer court means, and how that started to happen at Christ's ascension, continuing to this day. The explanation you seek follows::

> "Now, to apply the figure of the temple, the *entire* temple,
> precincts, outer court, the whole, answered to the measure of the
> stature of the fulness of Christ in those wonderful early days of the
> *ecclesia*, the fulfilment of the type of the temple. The whole of the house of God was thronged with sons. The visible church in its
> entirety answered to the indwelling of Father, Son and Holy Ghost, and
> included all that could be measured with the measure of Christ.
>
> But the Act of the Apostles is not Revelation, the last book to be
> written. By then the apostasy had begun to work... when 'they will not
> endure sound doctrine; but after their own lusts shall they heap to
> themselves teachers, having itching ears; and they shall turn away
> their ears from the truth, and shall be turned unto fables', II Tim.
> 4:3,4. **This is outer court religion.** This spread apace." (*Ibid*.
> p 257-8)

Those false teachers went out from the *ecclesia* - into the outer court - 'that they might be made manifest that they were not all of us', I John 2:19. So Jude confirms, "These be they who separate themselves" - from the apostles' doctrine and fellowship - "sensual, having not the Spirit" Jude vs. 19.

> "The outer court presents an external, visible profession of
> Christianity - precisely because it is the outer court; the thing seen
> first, the thing most conspicuous - having the form of godliness but
> denying the power thereof. Visible, because one cannot see inside the
> shrine, but one can enter and survey the court. This is the outward
> form of Christendom... In the outer court gathers a flock of goats
> bleating, 'Lord, Lord' and appearing to mean each word of it. Here are
> the workers of miracles; the casters out of demons; the sounding brass
> of a babel of tongues; in a word, the gifts without the Giver."
> (*Ibid*. pp 258-9)

The symbolism of the forty-two months is then mentioned (for it is not literal either). It speaks of the duration of the testimony of God's two witnesses, which appears again and again through the age. Revelation 11:3 has God sending them to show up publicly the take-over of the professing church by rotten outer-court religion. God's prophetic word judges mere profession devoid of the indwelling Holy Spirit. This measuring of true holiness (found in those allowed into the inner court) means that unholiness is cast out into the outer court. Ezekiel spoke of that symbolic measuring and judging of God in his day; John was given the vision that started with the beginning of the holy *ecclesia* on that Day of Pentecost, to continue till Christ returns. The outer court of unholy religiosity is truly crowded now.

**So the answer is**, ***it is not literal but spiritual measure, according to the measure of Christ, which started at the birth of Christ's Church at Pentecost, to continue till Christ returns***.

Answer (score 2):

The extent to which the language of any passage is figurative vs literal can be gauged by the surrounding language:

- Rev 11 begins with a reference to the "temple of God" - at the probable time that John wrote Revelation (last decade of 1st century) the Jerusalem temple did not exist and so the "temple of God" refers to something else - presumably either the church (1 Cor 3:16, 17), or the temple in heaven (Heb 8:1, 2), or Jesus' body (John 2:19-21).  In any case, it is a figurative reference as the Jerusalem temple is not referred to as "the temple of God".
- Rev 11:1 has John given a measuring rod to measure the temple, the altar and its worshipers.  This is clearly figurative.
- Rev 11:4 - the two witnesses are also two olive tree, two lampstands, who stand before the Lord of the earth.  This is also figurative language
- Rev 11:5 - fire from the mouth of witnesses is another figurative statement
- Rev 11:6 contains a direct reference to the prophets Moses and Elijah in a figurative way.

For a consistent hermeneutic, Rev 11:2, 3 and must be viewed as figurative language as well (see also 8).  The key to understanding Revelation's symbols to to find the Biblical precedent which in this case is possibly Luke 21:24 -

> They will fall by the edge of the sword and be led captive into all
> the nations. And Jerusalem will be trodden down by the Gentiles, until
> the times of the Gentiles are fulfilled.

This is the possible allusion here because both Rev 11:2, 3 and Luke 21:24 contain a reference to the Jerusalem being trampled by gentiles/nations.  There is also a an allusion to the Daniel's prophecies with 42 months and 1260 days being the same time period as the mentioned in Dan 7:25, 12:7, 12:11.  Note the helpful comments of Ellicott :

> (Rev 11:2) But the court . . .—Translate, **And the court which is
> outside the Temple cast out, and measure not it; because it was given
> to the nations (Gentiles)**: and they shall tread down the holy city
> forty and two months. The outer court—meaning, perhaps, all that lies
> outside the Temple itself—is to be omitted. ... It is the treading
> under of sacred things when the beast-power, or the world-power in
> men, tramples, like the swine, the pearls of grace under their feet,
> and turns fiercely upon those who gave them. Such an experience must
> the Church of Christ undergo. The shrine shall be safe, but the spirit
> of the nations, though nominally Christian, will be the spirit of
> Gentilism, worldliness, and even of violence. In the outer court of
> Church life there will be “the ebbing and flowing mass,” who “sit in
> the way of knowledge,” who “stand idle in the market-place,” who have
> no oil in their lamps, and who indirectly pave the way for utter
> worldliness and practical heathenism. But there is a limit to this
> desecration: forty and two months it is to last. The same length of
> time is expressed in different forms throughout the book. Sometimes we
> have twelve hundred and sixty days, as in Revelation 11:3 and in
> Revelation 12:6; at another time forty-two months, as here and in
> Revelation 13:5. A similar period seems to be meant in Revelation
> 12:14, where a time, times, and half a time is probably a way of
> expressing three years and a half; all three forms describe periods of
> the same length—not, of course, necessarily the same period. The idea
> is taken from Daniel, who uses such and similar expressions (Daniel
> 7:25; Daniel 12:7; Daniel 12:11). This incorporation of the
> expressions used by Daniel is one of those hints which remind us that
> the laws and principles of God’s government are the same in all ages:
> so that the principles which receive illustration in one set of
> historical events are likely to receive similar illustrations in after
> times; and that the prophecies of one era may contain seeds of
> fulfilments which spring to fruit in more than one age. ... but for
> the present, the period of forty and two months, the equivalent of
> three years and a half (the half of seven, the complete and divine
> number), is the symbol of a period limited in length, and under the
> control of Him who holds the seven stars and lives through the ages.
> It is the pilgrimage period of the Church, the period of the world’s
> power, during which it seems to triumph; but the period of sackcloth
> (see Revelation 11:3) and of suffering will not last forever.

Comment: Another great answer to the OP's question. I'm almost hesitant now to pen my own but I've already at least written it out, so it will follow shortly.

Comment: @Dottard Thank you for your contribution! The 3.5 times, 42 months and 1260 days as separate, I can't buy that; **"not, of course, necessarily the same period."** 3.5, 42 & 1260 that it would be separate times periods, but it's year, months, days (biblical years) 3.5 years = 42 months = 1260 days. Do you conclude that **"but for the present, the period of forty and two months, the equivalent of three years and a half"** that those tree sets of time are separate and we currently in the 42 months, are those 42 months literal?

Comment: @DanielDahlberg - the interpretation of the 1260 days, 42 months, 3½ years is another question whose interpretation depends on whether you are a preterist, historicist, futurist, or idealist in your prophetic understanding.  As another question, perhaps on Christianity Stack Exchange for that one.

Comment: @Dottard I wounder if you hold these tree numbers as different eras/times periods?

Comment: @DanielDahlberg - I personally believe they represent all the same period which is mentioned seven times - thrice in Daniel and four times in Revelation.

Comment: @Dottard Seems Elliot think they might be different, that's why I asked "not, of course, necessarily the same period. "

Comment: @DanielDahlberg - This is a great site for a variety of opinions and beliefs.  If you want to ask that question, please do so, but it may be better on Christianity Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Dottard Thanks I shall do that and see my two earlier attempts has been rejected and closed.

Comment: @Dottard strange it was there for 3 min then some moderator emigrated it over here

Answer (score 2):

The 42 months was literal, not figurative. Rev. 11:2 follows Rev. 11:1.

> *"And there was given to me a reed like to a rod, and the messenger stood, saying, `Rise, and measure the sanctuary of God, and the altar, and **those worshipping in it**;"* (YLT)

The people were still worshipping in that temple when the book was written. A reed, or rod... we might compare this rod to a yardstick. See Ezek. 40:3 where the angel has a measuring reed for the re-construction of the temple that was destroyed by Nebuchadnezzar.

The measuring of the inner sanctuary was symbolic of preserving the true and faithful worshipers just as the angel was to seal the righteous servants in Rev. 7:3 which were represented by the symbolic 144,000 - the 12 tribes multiplied by the perfect and complete symbol of 1,000.  To preserve, or keep from harm from the army that God was going to send to destroy Jerusalem and the temple.

There is no temple for the house of Israel today in Jerusalem, and has not been since AD 70.  In order for this prophesy to be used as something to come in our future, or any other future generation would require that a temple in Jerusalem be rebuilt, and then another army sent to destroy the city and that future temple a 3rd time.  The entire prophesy of Revelation was for the destruction of Jerusalem and that temple which was still in existence when the book was written.

The assumption that Revelation was written during the last decade of the 1st century AD is false, and stems from a misunderstanding or misuse of a statement made by Irenaeus who was referring to Nero and not Domitian.

> "“It was written in Patmos about A.D. 68, whither John had been banished by Domitius Nero, as stated in the title of the Syria version of the book; and with this concurs the express statement of Irenaeus in A.D. 175, who says it happened in the reign of Domitianou – i.e., Domitius (Nero).  Sulpicius, Orosius, etc., stupidly mistaking Domitianou for Domitianikos, supposed Irenaeus to refer to Domitian, A.D. 95, and most succeeding writers have fallen into the same blunder.  The internal testimony is wholly in favor of the early date. The temple at Jerusalem was still standing (ch. 11.1-10); the exact duration of the siege is foretold, viz., 42 months, 3(-)1/2 years, or 1260 days; the two witnesses are to be slain in the city where our Lord was crucified; Nero was reigning at the time, for it is said of the seven kings of Rome; ‘five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come, and when he cometh, he must continue a short space.’ The five kings are Julius Caesar, Augustus, Tiberius, Caligula, Claudius. The ‘one who is ‘ is Nero; the one who ‘must continue for a short space’ is Galba, who reigned only seven months. Everywhere the events are ‘to come quickly,’ lit. ‘with haste,’ or speed (ch. 1.1; 2.16; 3.11; 11.14; 22.7, 12, 20). The escape of the Christian Jews from Jerusalem to Pella is undoubtedly referred to in ch. 7.1-8, compared with Mat. 24.30.’”  (Source: Young's Analytical Concordance, 1885)  (1)

The Roman army destroyed the city and the temple in Jerusalem during the first Roman-Jewish war of AD 67-70, or in 42 months which is the equivalent of that same prophetic destruction told to Daniel of the "time, times, and a half" for the destruction of Jerusalem (Dan. 12:7).

Which is the same 1260 days (42 mos. x 30 days) or Rev. 11:3, or the last half of the last 7 years of Dan. 9:24 - 3-1/2 years.  Daniel was asking when the end of "these things" shall be, and so many people remove Dan. 12:6 from the entire context of the prophesy which began in Dan. 9 where Daniel asked for the end of the desolations (destruction) of JERUSALEM.

> *"17 and now, hearken, O our God, unto the prayer of Thy servant, and unto his supplication, and cause Thy face to shine on **Thy sanctuary that [is] desolate, for the Lord's sake.***

> *18 `Incline, O my God, Thine ear, and hear, open Thine eyes and see our desolations, **and the city on which Thy name is called**; for not for our righteous acts are we causing our supplications to fall before Thee, but for Thy mercies that [are] many."*  (Dan. 9:17-18, YLT)

And Gabriel told Daniel:

> *"`Seventy weeks are determined for **thy people, and for thy holy city**, to shut up the transgression, and to seal up sins, and to cover iniquity, and to bring in righteousness age-during, and to seal up vision and prophet, and to anoint the holy of holies."*  (Dan. 9:24, YLT)  (2) (3)

Daniel 12 was still discussing the prophesy begun in Daniel 9 which concerned Daniel's people (the Jews) and Daniel's holy city(Jerusalem).  The end of those things was the end of the earthly animal sacrificial system under the earthly carnal Mosaic covenant.

The birthing of the spiritual out of the carnal or fleshly system occurred at the end of the days of the destruction of earthly Jerusalem and the physical Mosaic temple.  The earthly or natural comes first, and then the spiritual (1 Cor. 15:42-49).  The resurrected new Jerusalem and new temple was spiritual, not physical.

All of Revelation was the prophesy of Christ's coming in judgment of that natural earthly temple system in Jerusalem which was finished in AD 70 when the Romans burned the city and tore down the stones (Matt. 24:2) during the 42 months of that war in the 1st century AD.  It has already happened.

Notes:

1. Signs of Revelation, Part I: The Time of His Coming [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/02/23/the-signs-of-revelation-part-i-the-time-of-his-coming/)
2. The Seventy Weeks of Daniel Chap. 9 [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/09/09/seventy-weeks-of-daniel-chap-9/)
3. Daniel and the End Times [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/05/09/daniel-and-the-end-times/)

Comment: Thank you Gina for your contribution +1! Do you mean 260 days (42 mos. x 30 days) or Rev. 11:3 was fulfilled 67-70 A.D. if I understood it right do you think then it has a dubble fulfillment?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the Preterist view IMO is a 'Pretentious' view. I agree that the 42 months, itself, as pertaining to the verse in question at least, is of a literal nature but I can't agree with your timing. There were, however, two, not one, 'other' 3.5 year periods surrounding the 2nd temple destruction!! We both, however, also agree that there will be no 3rd temple, of a literal nature, in Jerusalem. From what I remember of my own investigation of the timing of John's revelation, I did not come to your conclusion but it has been awhile and I may just have to look into it again.

Comment: After spending the last several hours looking into the possibility of an earlier date to the writing of the book of Revelation, I can now cite the following: As to the theory that Revelation was written by John in the late 60's (as opposed to 90's), under the emperor Lucius Domitius Ahenobarbus, who took the name "Nero", this Idea would seem to have been promulgated by one well-known spokesman, for the 'theonomist' (pre 70 AD) camp, namely one Kenneth L Gentry, in 1989. Inconsistency, however, marks Gentry's hermeneutical pattern, which was well and truly dismissed...tbc...

Comment: ...by one Robert L Thomas, Professor of New Testament, in 1994. See following link:https://www.tms.edu/m/tmsj5i.pdf - Irenaeus, would appear therefore to have not been in error, when attributing the reign of Domitian to the time of writing, rather than 'Domitius', as it were. In light of this further, to all intents and purposes, 'incorrect' exegesis, it is therefore a downvote from me.

Comment: @DanielDahlberg - Revelation was the "double fulfillment  of the 1st destruction of Jerusalem and the temple about 586 BC by Nebuchadnezzar.  The 2nd by Vespasian and his son Titus under the Roman army.  Those who heard this prophesy in the 1st century AD knew Christ's return was coming to them "soon" in their lifetime, their generation..  There is no end to an everlasting kingdom.  Revelation was the end of the old covenant, but the beginning of the new covenant under the gospel of Christ for all generations to the ages of the ages (Eph. 3:21).

Comment: @OldeEnglish - Your research is incomplete.  First audience perspective is required for proper hermeneutics.  If Rev had been written after the destruction of the temple it would have had to have been mentioned in the prophesy. The temple was the center of the Jewish world. That the temple is no where represented in the book has having already been destroyed is clear evidence that it was still in operation when the book was written.

Comment: @Gina The prophecy they heard and knew that Messiah was coming was that by prophet Daniel gave of weeks! I believe that the 1260 had a literal 70 A.D and will have a symbolic/spiritual fulfillment in the tribulation.

Comment: The book of Revelation was not a revealing of John's, it was a revealing of Jesus Christ's and therefore more of a dictation. John may well have had first audience perspective but he was to write about more of a future perspective, not the past. The temple was at that time of writing already history, gone, no more. The revealing provides an all-embracing vision of what God purposes for mankind, and that brings the grand theme of the Bible, the sanctification of Jehovah's name and the vindication of his sovereignty by means of the kingdom under Christ, the promised seed, to a glorious climax.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - the future tense verbs and words were yet future to those of that generation.  They were still waiting for that temple to be torn down.  Their future in their lifetime is not our future.  Their future is our past.  Christ did everything He said He was going to do,  fulfilled all of the prophesies of the OT just as He promised.  The temple was still standing when the book was written.  The climax was the fully established kingdom, the fullness of the gospel of Christ under the new covenant which has been in operation ever since.

Comment: We will obviously never agree on this. I have exposed the 'fantasies' that you espouse and you still talk as if you have never been found out. Sigh !! I have nothing further to say to you, except maybe that I hope God still blesses you, for you still have a fair amount of relevance.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - TY for the blessing.  Perspective, point of view is critical to see it.  For those who believe that Christ did not finish His work, then they must also believe that we are still living under the old Mosaic laws (Matt. 24:34).  I would ask that you at least consider my post "Perspective" at the top menu of my blog - ShreddingTheVeil.org.

Comment: @DanielDahlberg - a double fulfillment of what ?  You expect a 3rd destruction of Jerusalem & of a temple that does not exist?

Comment: @Gina I mena just as Robert explained in his answer it's the first one under my question

Answer (score 2):

**Revelation 11:2, literal or figurative?**

I believe, wholeheartedly, that we are talking figuratively here, with regard to the temple sanctuary and its altar, not to mention the outer court. As a consequence, we can neither be talking about the 2nd temple, nor even a 3rd, for it can only be symbolic, spiritual even. As for the courtyard, which is attributable to the Gentile nations, it is to be excluded from John's measuring, suggesting that certain ones of these, at least, will be outside the protection of God.

The setting here is between the blowing of the 6th trumpet and the 7th and final trumpet and is therefore yet future, or could even be to do with the 'here and now'. [ I am not, however, an advocate for the '7 year tribulation' period, as I believe the 70th week of Daniel's prophecy was fulfilled in the 1st Century, i.e. 66 AD thru 73 AD, as I have expressed numerous times on this site, but that's by the way here ].

The temple sanctuary and altar, as such, is being shown to be in survival mode. It is the symbolic outer courtyard, that is to be cast clear out, without being measured, it having been given over to the Nations/Gentiles, who are to, subsequently, tread under foot the holy city (so called, New Jerusalem) for 42 months. The 42 months **(1260 days)**, as at least pertaining to this particular verse (for there are other same length periods in Revelation and Daniel) could be past, present or future and even part of an even bigger number. However, for the eschatologists among us, we cannot help but feel that September 11, 2001, may have indeed heralded the beginning of the end. The **4 blood red moons** of 2014 and 2015 AD, making for the last of **10 'tetrads'** in the 'Common Era', the first being that of 32 and 33 AD, which culminated in the **'Ransom Sacrifice'**, may yet yield their significance in the unrelenting march of time since. The number 10, after all, signifies completeness. One should probably take note of the fact that it has not even been **2300 evenings and mornings** since 2015's end of September(09/28/2015), final blood red moon of the possible, all encompassing, 10th tetrad.

I will close here with Daniel's  13th and 14th verses of his 8th chapter, widely accepted as being of a dual prophetic nature.

**Dan, 8:13,14 [NASB]:-**

...*13) Then I heard a holy one speaking, and another holy one said to that particular one who was speaking, " How long will the vision about the regular sacrifice apply, while the transgression causes horror, so as to allow both the holy place and the host to be trampled?" 14) And he said to me, " For **2300 evenings and mornings**; then the holy place will be properly restored."*

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Olde +1. All seems to agree that it's talking about a figuratively language, Gina as you that lean at a fulfillment 70 A.D of the times sequence while to other also see it as being figurative. From when in 2015 do you count the 2300 Days of Daniel 8:14?

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. I will have to get back to you regarding not one but two aspects of your comment here, as I've stayed up way past my bed time, it now being 5:34 in the morning here in Colorado, USA.

Comment: @DanielDahlberg-Although I am of the belief that the "Great Tribulation" was a 1st Cent. happening, that does not mean that there won't still be some kind of tribulation, to involve a certain "Man of Lawlessness" (a deluding "Demagogue", much like that of a Donald Trump quite frankly, see 2 Thess, 2:1-12) to precede the time of the "Second Advent", leading into ARMAGEDDON, which will admittedly involve many more people and therefore be on a much bigger scale... When Jesus talked to his disciples on the "Mount of Olives", not long before his death, and warned them of the coming...tbc...

Comment: ...TRIBULATION, which was to be GREAT, he said that, same would come in their life times and before all the Jewish generation of that time had passed away. Within the next 40 years, the full 'horror' of that prophecy came true.... As for the 2300 days, which may well in corporate the last 1335 days (see Dan, 12:12), there obviously could be a number of starting points. If taken from the last blood red moon of 2015, we are talking 1st week of Jan, 2022, for the end. If, however, I and many others (not of this site) are correct in assuming DT could be the M of L, then the end could be ...tbc...

Comment: ...as early as 10/02/21, that being 2300 days from his infamous escalator ride of 06/16/2015, when he announced his candidacy for PRESIDENT. One could of course assume the starting point to be that of 11/08/2016, when he actually won the Presidency, against all odds, or even take from 01/20/2017, when he actually became President. When DT's actual Presidency was over, I had discounted this theory, but as we all know, or indeed should know, he is still very much DELUDING and therefore still very much RELEVANT. No 'normal' person should be able to wield such 'belligerent' power, should they???

Comment: @DanielDahlberg- sorry, I meant mid mid Jan, 2022, for my first scenario, as the last blood red moon of 2015 was on 09/28/2015 and not mid 2015 and 'in corporate', of course, should be all one word. Incidentally, Trump was actually born on a blood red moon!!!

Comment: As I said to Gina, I believe that the 1260 had a literal 70 A.D and will have a symbolic/spiritual fulfillment in the tribulation. I doubt that DT has anything to do with the character mentioned in 2Thess2 it will be a man the whole world will fear, DT is only feared by leftists.

Comment: @DanielDahlberg- The whole world lives and breathes by what goes on in the 'United States of America'. It is therefore the perfect place for the M of L/Antichrist to spread his satanic influence. For you to say that... DT is only feared by leftists, is absolute 'hogwash' !!!

Comment: what's M of L. We laugh at him here in Europe and see him as a fat clown but I don't know you he might feel fear for him..

Comment: @DanielDahlberg- No need to go to chat. I'm done here. What's M of L? really!! M of L=Man of Lawlessness, as I pointed out to you in my second comment to you. This term is also used in 2 Thess 2:1 thru 12.

Comment: "No need to go to chat" why do make a statement as if I asked to go to the chat?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this passage should be interpreted under the understanding that the Christian community itself is the "temple of God" for the New Testament era.

That statement is based on 1 Corinthians ch3 v16; "Do you not know that you [plural] are God's temple [singular] and that God's Sprit dwells in you [plural]?" (RSV)

The second half of that verse explains the first. In principle, a temple is a place where a god dwells. Through his Spirit, this God dwells in "you", that is in his community (the "building" metaphor was introduced earlier in the chapter). Therefore the community is his temple. In the context, the point is that anyone who breaks up the community is guilty of the heinous crime of destroying a temple (v17).

This identification allows us to interpret the Revelation passage in a figurative way.

The "outer court" given over to the "nations" represents the external structures of the church, physical and organisational, which may fall into hostile hands. I suggest that the beast being allowed to "conquer the saints" (Revelation ch13 v7) has the same meaning. I suggest that the "man of lawlessness" being able to "take his seat in the temple of God" (1 Thessalonians ch2 v4) has the same meaning. A purely superficial victory.

"The altar and those who worship there", measured as the true temple on the analogy of Ezekiel ch40, represent the inner core of believers with unquenchable faith, which stubbornly testifies to the world from v3 onwards. Presumably these are the same people who were "sealed" as God's property in ch7.

Perhaps I had better add, to avoid misunderstanding, that I am not seeking to identify these people with any existing group, denomination, or organisation. Especially not Jehovah's Witnesses.

This all falls into Revelation's depiction of a supreme and final crisis of persecution, which hasn't happened yet. Therefore future.

In short, the figurative interpretation works, and contributes towards a coherent message.

P.S. I have a book which covers these things in more detail;
[http://amazon.com/Silence-Heaven-Survey-Book-Revelation/dp/1597556734](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597556734)

Answer (score 0):

I feel I need to provide another outline for consideration. However this outline contradicts, and confronts the several others already posted at this time, so may receive some pushback.

Revelation 11:2 is describing a literal event. But, within this, the ‘measuring’ is using figurative language/scenario to convey something that is part of the ‘literal’ scene being witnessed.

The vision is outlining that the ‘use’ of the (inner) temple will need to comply with Torah. That is, the ‘workings’ of the temple, the way it is to be used, will need to be ‘measured’ (made to fit, comply with) what is outlined in Torah -

**DANIEL 5:27** *Tekel, you have been weighed in the balances and found wanting;*

Here we ‘see’ an example of how the Old Testament uses measuring ‘terms’ to describe behaviour, or ‘practices’. So the ‘use’ of ‘measuring’ terminology is commonly used to ‘measure’ behaviour, in this case ‘temple practice’. The Temple will operate ‘by the book’ *so to speak*. Revelation is essentially a book written from a Hebraic perspective - and utilises ‘Old Testament’ ‘thinking’ - so it *needs* to be interpreted from this perspective.

But, the temple itself is (will be) literal. So the passage in Revelation 11:2 is describing a literal situation. There will be a [3rd] temple built. And the outside court will not be, or rather is specifically specified *not* to be considered.

One passage assumed those (like myself) who hold to this ‘third temple’ view that it relates to that (again literal!) temple outlined in Ezekiel 40/41, but *that* temple is (will be) the Millennium temple. (It’s far too large to fit on the current temple mound!)

Let’s look at some foundational ‘views’ that sûpport this ‘literal’ interpretation.

Jesus in his first visit …

**LUKE 4:18** *The Spirit of the Lord is upon me, because he has anointed me to proclaim good news to the poor. He has sent me to proclaim liberty to the captives and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty those who are oppressed,* **19** *to proclaim the year of the Lord's favor.”*

But he failed to read the concluding passage!

**ISAIAH 61:2** *to proclaim the year of the Lord's favor,* ***and the day of vengeance of our God,*** *to comfort all who mourn;*

Revelation is about this part Jesus did *not* quote in Luke 4 - because that part did *not* (yet) fulfil on his first coming. And to fulfil this ….. *he needs Israel*. This statement will meet pushback from some, but it is an alternative view that some have - hence I’m outlining this for consideration.

This period (Revelation) is all about Israel. Revelation is about setting up for - and then describing Daniels 70th week.

The ‘end times’ is about Jesus, as Messiah, representing Israel (once they repent and accept him - which the Tribulation will drive them to do!) - [righteously] defeating the [literal and. Multiple] spiritual entities behind evil - who will be ‘using’ the nations as their means.

**DANIEL 9:24** *”Seventy weeks are decreed about your people and your holy city,*”

A Holy city needs a sanctuary. A Temple. And a Messiah! But, Israel rejected the/their Messiah.

**DANIEL 9:26** *And after the sixty-two weeks, an anointed one shall be cut off and shall have nothing. And the people of the prince who is to come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary.*

This is arguably a poor translation. Young’s gets closer to the correct. The Messiah is cut of from his people. Stop. The ‘70’ weeks stops after 69. And this results in the temple shortly after being destroyed. But for the 70th week to restart, continue and then*be* completed, it (the Temple) will **have to** be rebuilt **first**!

He Dead Sea scrolls help with some understanding of ‘ages’ and ‘times. But, that to one side, let’s stay with scripture…

**LUKE 21:24** *They will fall by the edge of the sword and be led captive among all nations, and Jerusalem will be trampled underfoot by the Gentiles, until the times of the Gentiles are fulfilled.*

Luke 21 compliments Matthew 24, Jesus talking about the times of the end. The Gentiles have a ‘set’ amount of time. Some (unfortunately) loosely term this ‘the age of Grace’. Nevertheless an (set/literal) amount of ‘time’ has been ‘given’ to the nations (aka Gentiles) - and they will trample the Temple court’s until that time is over - then the 70th week can finally complete.

Yes - Revelation 11:2 is quite literal. Time will tell!!!

Comment: I'm sorry Dave, but I have to push back on this. IMO, it is full of misconceptions. It's a downvote from me, but at least not an anonymous one.

Comment: @Olde English Thanks! appreciate the accompanying comment!  As alluded to in the outline, I expected (negative) reaction. But - Am curious about what you are calling misconceptions, but you don’t have to continue this line if you don’t want to. Cheers!

Comment: I'm sorry, again, Dave but I've been on this particular Q. and A. not to mention C. for the best part of the last 16 hours and only got 3 hours sleep last night. I think, however, I mentioned something to you before, regarding the '70 weeks' prophecy at least, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Olde English Ahhh, I now ‘see’ where your coming from. I had read the other answers, but hadn’t until now noted the authors - we simply aren’t going to see eye to eye, at all, so let’s leave this. (LOL - you suggested my contribution is ‘*full of misconceptions*’ - so are you claiming yours isn’t? :-))

Comment: Ok, Dave. Firstly, there will be no 3rd 'literal' temple built. We are talking symbolism, not only of the temple itself but also of the courtyard. Secondly, Ezekiel is talking about the 2nd temple. Slaughtering/sacrifices; guardrooms in the Millennial temple?? I don't think so. Thirdly, Daniel's 70th week IMO was the 7 year period of 66 AD thru 73 AD. The dispensationalist theory just doesn't hold water. Fourthly, the 'end times' will involve the whole world, not just Israel. Five, the holy cities sanctuary/temple was still standing at the start of the 70th week....tbc...

Comment: ...The Messiah will be cut-off/crucified at the end of the 69th week (33 AD). Finally, Luke 21:24a is about 70 AD and 21:24b is a duel prophecy. So, now, maybe, you can see where I'm 'truly' coming from and why I think your answer was 'full of misconceptions'. Can I 'truly" claim that my answer is free of misconceptions? Absolutely not, particularly as I have gone out on a limb in no uncertain terms, at least with regard to the 'Trump" scenario, but if the shoe fits...one should at least talk about the possibility. If the watchman sees the sword coming..... Ezek 33:6

Comment: @Dave I don't agree to the answer but I at least could neutralize the -1 to a 0.

Comment: @Olde English Appreciate your follow up. Comments, apart from clarifying or answering Qs, are not really an ideal means to engage in argument/debate -  and besides, we all know that these eschatological ‘debates’ won’t change minds, but only ‘raise temperatures’. Your view has support here - mine was put up fully knowing it countered these (and attract pushback) - but nevertheless ‘readers’ should be made aware that there are other viewpoints, and get a ‘glimpse’ of them. Much as I would love to respond and ‘straighten out’ those points you raised, probably best to leave it here. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Research into Revelation 11:2 literal or figurative? is better understood if one accesses the Siener Van Rensburg - documents/visions (aka Krausa document); please Google 'Siener van Rensburg' for better detail otherwise read on my brief synopsis.

Briefly, Siener van Renburg, made famous during the Anglo-Boer War 1899-1901, a layman preacher/dominee who served alongside General De  La Rey, the Afrikaners (+-80 000) were up against Imperial Britain (+-480 000). Siener via his vision, as the war, started informed the Afrikaners that they would lose the war and their women and children were to be incarcerated into camps (the World's first Concentration Camps before the German Death camps of WW2).

Siener's study of the Bible drew so much ire (the British were supposed to thrash the Boers in 6 months, instead it went on till 1901 exhausting Britain/England) from the British that after the Anglo-Boer War they held 2 formal committee reviews (1 - Military, 2 - Legal) into the guy Siener van Rensburg. The aim of the committees was to 'trash' him or show him as a phony who led the General de la Rey on via deception/intrigue, and not via his Biblical knowledge which was applied practically to the battlefield too. To those that have read this far, a juicy titbit, while in court the English judge "forbade him to have any visions" to which he replied "but I can't I'm having one now . . . my son is dead", the judge annoyed, was interrupted by a court messenger that delivered to the judge a note, the judge ripped open the note and read out allowed "your son has died". Thus was Siener's power of Gospel/Biblical facts and insight, all provided by God for your study/review.

Now, briefly, Siener (whom I studied diligently 2016 - till now), attributed his visions to the Christian God, he read (just get this), only the  Bible (New & Old Testament), yet he was able to interpret all Biblical events, not only that, he is able to predict the coming of WW3 (UK will swap sides (Brexit is now) and join Russia just before WW3 starts). Every vision he had, related to the Biblical events, and those in Revelations, actually happened (he provided insight into the plagues - too much to add here in this short synopsis), such that the famous Revelation 11:3–12 is a description of two individuals, these two are in fact Pope Benedict and Pope Francis, who represent the Church on Earth, both will be captured during WW3 (by Russia-UK), executed/martyred and after 3.5 years, once the Axis forces are driven back, the Church will be restored (both come to life and are taken up to heaven before all mankind).

Thus Revelation 11:2 is more literal, though if one cannot fit the pattern(which Siener did), then it, Revelation 11:2 becomes figurative.

Comment: If this is your first posting to this site, then I'm sorry that I have to downvote same. This is bordering on exegetical nonsense. Please take the time to check out what this site is all about, under our 'Code of Conduct', if you still feel inclined to post again that is. In my first post, I also stumbled right at the "get go'.

Comment: @christianitysa Hi Chrisy, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!